# Css effect to make font look dirty/textured

Tags: css, fonts

I want to use a font [from here](https://fontlot.com/186422/flesh-and-blood-display-font/). Like you can see, there is a preview image ontop and a small field down below where you can write an example text.

The font is like every other font, meaning only black. Is it possible with css to mimic the texture that is used in the preview image? I mean the dark spots. The white spots that are not on the font can be ignored.

[Preview Front with texture](https://i1.wp.com/fontlot.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/flesh-and-blood-font.jpg?resize=700%2C387&ssl=1)

Comment: Investigate CSS mask with text on a background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example of text clipping the background of its element using CSS background-clip (note, this is not completely standard and some browsers require a prefix and it is not compatible with IE):

```css
.fontBg {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1016/300/100);
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="fontBg">HERE IS SOME TEXT</div>
```

Comment: OK I get it. It's not that something is added ontop of the font (like black dots to a white font) but more like the font gets transparent so a background image can be seen. Now I just need to find a fitting background texture.